# Symfony Voters: Access Denied

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony4-voter

Is it normal when `supports()` returns `false`, it results `Access Denied`? According the Doc, Voter should end-up on supports so I assume an access should be granted.

> **Voter::supports($attribute, $subject)**
>
> When isGranted() (or denyAccessUnlessGranted()) is called, the first
>   argument is passed here as $attribute (e.g. ROLE_USER, edit) and the
>   second argument (if any) is passed as $subject (e.g. null, a Post
>   object). Your job is to determine if your voter should vote on the
>   attribute/subject combination. If you return true, voteOnAttribute()
>   will be called. Otherwise, your voter is done: some other voter should
>   process this. In this example, you return true if the attribute is
>   view or edit and if the object is a Post instance.

Comment: You get access denied when no voter grants access.

Comment: So you mean, if there is `denyAccessUnlessGranted('something', $foo);` and a `Voter::supports()` returns `false`, `Access Denied` is expected because nothing is granting an access. I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `Voter::supports()`. You get access denied because access hasn't been granted to you by any voter. Nothing more nothing less.